# Where do I find main() in VC++?

Tags: visual-c++, program-entry-point

VC++ is basically a C++ program so where is main() located in it? I'm using Microsoft visual C++ 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft enhanced the C and C++ languages when targeting Windows: they use a function called `wmain` which can take a wide character command line argument. It can have the prototypes:

```
int wmain()
int wmain( int argc, wchar_t* argv[] )
```

You might also see `WinMain` or `wWinMain` as alternatives.

So despite what the standard says, you will not see a function `main` with Windows apps.